# What does "??" mean in standard ML

Tags: sml, ml

I was looking at this ML code and I saw this statement

```
fun doSomething (a, b) = 
    if a < b then ?? else ?? ;
```

What does the "??" in this context mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically thinking, then statement would equal else statement. Could it be simply forgotten to complete statements and temporary place `??`'s?
None of the [operators](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Standard_ML_Programming/Expressions) seem to represent what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh wait nevermind you are right. I was reading the code in the "Exercises" section of this book. I'm dumb.